# Meaning of 'teenage' in 'teenage copywriters'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From [Ad nausea hits the grey market](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/business/4019965.stm), a BBC online article:

> The use of the famous, or nearly famous, is frequently seen as the last gasp of a
>   copywriter running short of inspiration. In fact, argues Mr Treguer, celebrity
>   role models – what he calls ‘generational heroes’ – can deliver the goods. In France,
>   advertisers use a range of celebrities *d’un  certain age* **[I don’t know why there’s French here. Does anyone?]**, but still with some va- va-voom: Catherine Deneuve, Johnny Hallyday, former cyclist Raymond Poulidor – at 66 still the country’s favourite sportsman.
>
> In Britain, meanwhile, the market is sewn up by a small gerontocracy of actors –
>   notably former comic actress June Whitfi eld, whose perennial reappearance as the face
>   of the elderly provokes cries of despair. ‘These are precisely the sorts of ads that are
>   made by the **teenage** copywriters,’ groans Mr Starkey.

I recognise but am still confused by [ODO's Definition 1.1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/teenage):

> Relating to or characteristic of teenagers

I guess that Mr. Starkey's usage is not literal, but because **teenage** copywriters are rare,  why not use another apter word to disparage/deride the copywriters?

Or am I wrong? This quote confuses me, because in the first para praises the use of famous actors, which the second denounces. The article doesn't explicitly distinguish their use in France from England?

Comment: The author is saying that in France there is greater variety in the use of older celebrities than there is in England, where only one former comic is said to be the "go-to" celebrity when an older well-known face is called for. "Teenage" is probably meant to be taken as an exaggeration. The author is saying that the young British copywriters have a very narrow range of experience and always choose the same celebrity.  But are copywriters in charge of casting? I doubt it.

Comment: A guess as to why the author uses French (d'un) is simply that they are talking about what happens in France regarding French celebrities, thus resorting to the French *d'un* fits the context. Second, and perhaps more importantly, I assume the author knows (or has studied) some French and perhaps to him/her *d'un* just sounds better than *of a,* especially given the context. In general, there are hundreds of French expressions used in English, including *bon mot* and *savoir-fare* that, among other things, sound better than an English equivalent would.

Comment: No, borrowing *d'un* by itself would be silly and gratuitous.  The French here is *d'un certain âge*, not just *d'un*; look up the entire expression.

Comment: I looked up the original article, and found that as @snailboat suggests, the entire phrase _d'un certain age_ was italicized.

Answer (score 2):

The use of "teenage" here is intended to convey inexperience and possibly lack of judgment - attributes often ascribed to teenagers (in the United States, at least; I can't speak for elsewhere).

As for why there's French there, it is because, first, as CarSmack noted, that it is talking about people in France; second, there is a connotation of sophistication, haughtiness, or "upper-class" culture associated with French, and this connotation augments the emotional impact of the idiom "of a certain age".
Note that only "of a" is converted to French; the author's intended audience would not recognize the idiom if "certain age" were in French.

"Of a certain age", meanwhile, is a phrase deriving from the practice of women who state a different, usually lower, number for their age (or none at all) on account of being embarrassed or ashamed about how high the actual number is - my understanding is that this actual number may be anywhere between thirty and sixty years.

Overall, the contrast between the two countries is intended to be the number of older celebrities used as references; the premise is that Britain uses fewer, and that this is a bad thing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the author meant "certain age" to be read in French after _d'un_, even though the circonflexe seems to have been lost.

Comment: Perhaps so; but French is not, to my knowledge, widely understood in either the UK (where I believe this article was written - see http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/business/4019965.stm) or the US. The fact that there *are* French words "certain âge", and that they mean essentially the same thing as the English ones, might as well be coincidence for many readers (even if it wasn't for the writer).

Comment: "d'un certain âge" is a term can be used to describe people of age (60ish +) in French. That paragraph of the article is about France anyway, and the term, even tho not English, is still intuitively understandable for English speaking people. So maybe the author simply thought it would fit in well - which it does, if you ask me.  I've seen French expressions being used in the US/UK - e.g. I have seen some use of "c'est la vie" in US TV-shows for instance.

Answer (score 2):

*Teenagers* is used here to emphasize the generational divide between those at whom ads are targetted and the creators of those ads.  Mr Starkey believes that British copywriters trying to appeal to an older audience do so by hiring from a small pool of older celebs (the *gerontocracy* ).  He believes these copywriters do this because they don't understand what appeals to and motivates older generations.  Why not?  Because they are so young.  They are practically *teenagers* compared to the targets of their ads.

*D'un certain  âge*, by the way, was italicized in the original article (albeit missing the circumflex on the  *â*).  The whole phrase is French, and means "older."  The writer uses it here because there are only so many ways to say *senior citizen* in English, and he wants to not repeat them too many times (hence the obscure word *gerontocracy.* )  It is natural, therefore, to use a French idiom for "older" in the paragraph that addresses advertising for the elderly France.  *D'un certain  âge* provides one euphemism for *older.*

Here's a partial list of the ways the author refers to senior citizens in the original article:

> *the over-50s,
>   elderly consumers,
>   someone over 40,
>   a broader age-group,
>   older shoppers ,
>   ageing swimmer ,
>   older drinkers,
>   "generational heroes," 
>    **celebrities d'un certain âge,** 
>   gerontocracy of actors,
>   the elderly,
>   an ageing strongman,
>   an older audience,
>   old people ,
>   older people,
>   elderly consumers,
>   the old*